# Empirical Standard Deviation in R

Tags: r, statistics

Is the following correct?

Suppose we simulate 1000 the following model: y = beta*x + error.

Then, we are going to get 1000 beta hat.

The sample mean is beta bar= (beta1 hat +beta2 hat +...+beta1000 hat)/1000

The empirical standard deviation is sqrt(sum(beta_i  hat - beta bar)/n-1) were i=1,2,.., 1000 and n is the length of y.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what exactly you want to do, but if you have a linear regression, like in the model "y=beta*x + error", you estimate only 1 beta. This is your beta hat. Your estimated coefficient. Then you can calculate your estimated values for y, its called y hat.

So your estimated y would be:

beta hat*x1, beta hat*x2, ..., beta hat*xn = y1 hat, y2 hat, ..., yn hat.

The estimated mean is then:

(y1 hat + y2 hat + ... + yn hat)/n

Then is the question whether you need the standard deviation of your estimated y, y hat, or the residual standard error (RSE) or the standard deviation of your original data, y or x.

The formular to estimate a standard deviation is:

sqrt (sum_i=1^n ((x_i -mean(x))^2)/(n-1))

Hope it can help a bit

Comment: Thank for your replaying. I am asking for the empirical standard deviation.

Comment: If you need the empirical standard deviation of your original data, you need do do this with "x" or "y", if you need it from the estimated data you should do it with "y hat"